# undefined class/module YAML::PrivateType

Tags: rubygems, yaml, private-methods

I have uploaded a new version of gem to the server, successfully. If i
install the gem from local, its successfully installed.

But I'm getting following error while installing the same gem from
remote server.

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    undefined class/module YAML::PrivateType

Note:

I have included a method outside of any class/module. Is there any issue
with that?

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in rubygems 1.5.0. Downgrade to 1.3.7 (theoretically the bug has been fixed in 1.5.2 but I have not tested this yet).